# Custom Sort function does not work

Tags: c#, sorting

I have implemented a custom sort function for a list. But after calling it, the order of the list does not seem to change.

I want to find the largest number that comes from the combination of all numbers. e.g., give 540, 9, it should output 9540 instead of 5409. So The compare function does the job.

```
    public void LargestPossibleNumberCombination(List<int> nums) {
        nums.Sort(CustomCompare);

    }
    public int CustomCompare(int x, int y)
    {
        string a = x +""+ y;
        string b = y + "" + x;
        return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more constructive in commenting?

Comment: We can not guess what you want to achieve. Please describe what you mean by a _number combination_. You are acutally comparing a _string concatenation of numbers_. Please give at least an example input and an expected output.

Comment: Where is the custom sort function?

Comment: I want to find the largest number that comes from the combination of all numbers. e.g., give 540, 9, it should output 9540 instead of 5409. So The compare function does the job.

Comment: "0" means that they are both equals. Why do you return "0" when 'a' is 'bigger' than 'b'? What will happen if you'll write "return a.CompareTo(b);" as the last statement in your custom compare function?

Comment: return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? -1 : 1; solves the issue.

Comment: `return -a.CompareTo(b)` should works

Comment: or just `b.CompareTo(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value when `x` is less than `y` (<0), when `y` is less than `x` (>0) and when are equals (0).

However you can make this sort more compact using a lambda comparison:

```
nums.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(string.Format("{0}{1}", y, x), 
                                   string.Format("{0}{1}", x, y)));
```

If you want to join the list after being sorted:

```
var result = string.Join("", nums);
```